# Optional.of not working with generic parameter in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Why this doesn't compile?

```
fun <T> returnOptionalOf(t: T): Optional<T> {
    val optional: Optional<T> = Optional.of(t)
    return optional
}
```

The error is

> Type mismatch: inferred type is T but T & Any was expected

How to make it work?

This compiles just fine:

```
fun returnOptionalOfString(t: String): Optional<String> {
    val optional: Optional<String> = Optional.of(t)
    return optional
}
```

Comment: Is it on purpose that your function accepts nullable types?

Comment: This is simplified example of more complex problem that I have, where I don't control function that returns T parameter. But I tried to use `Optional.ofNullable` which accepts a nullable parameter and it doesn't affect the problem. What's more, just `Optional.empty<T>()` is not working as well.

Comment: @Slaw It's not a bug. See my answer.

Comment: Yes, I realized it's intended behavior after the fact. Running on 1.8.21 emits a warning, saying it will become an error in future versions, that points to [KT-36770](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-36770/Prohibit-unsafe-calls-with-expected-NotNull-T-and-given-Kotlin-generic-parameter-with-nullable-bound).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My first advice would be to just avoid `Optional` types in Kotlin. Nullable types offer the same compile-time guarantees about whether a value can hold nulls, they force you to check for null in the right places, and they are more idiomatic (there is also plenty of syntax sugar that will help deal with nullable values, such as `?:` or `?.` operators).

Now back to your specific question, what you see is the combination of several things working against you:

- in your function signature, you didn't constrain `T` at all. This means that `T` could be a nullable type (for instance, `String?`), which in turn would mean that this function accepts nulls. Note that `Optional.of` is a Java function that expects a non-null value, and throws NPE if given `null` as argument. You might want to double check whether throwing NPE is what you intended for your function in this case.
- the other (bigger) problem is that you might be assuming that `Optional<T>` is covariant in `T`, but it's actually invariant (probably because it's a Java class and nothing special was done about it, but there is [an issue to change this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-54889)). To put it more clearly, this means that `Optional<A>` is not a subtype of `Optional<B>` even if `A` is a subtype of `B`, and thus you cannot assign an `Optional<String>` value to a variable with type `Optional<String?>`.
- the third thing is that `Optional` factory functions like `of` and `ofNullable` actually return the non-nullable projection of the type you pass, so always `Optional<T & Any>` (because a null value will respectively fail or result in an empty `Optional`). For instance, `Optional.of<String?>("abc")`  still returns an `Optional<String>`, which doesn't play well with the fact that `Optional` is invariant in `T`.

This explains why your explicit type (`Optional<T>`) of the `optional` variable is incorrect. Because `Optional.of` returns a `Optional<T & Any>` , which cannot be assigned to a variable of type `Optional<T>` (even though `T & Any` is a subtype of `T`).

This might be a lot of jargon, so let me clarify by using your string example, but instead of using `String` as `T` let's use `String?`:

```kotlin
fun returnOptionalOfString(t: String?): Optional<String?> {
    val optional: Optional<String?> = Optional.of(t) // error here
    return optional
}
```

Here you'll see the same error for the assignment, but in easier terms.

As @marstran already mentioned, one way to solve all of this is to just use non-nullable types when dealing with `Optional`s. In your case, this means constraining `T` using `: Any`:

```kotlin
fun <T : Any> returnOptionalOf(t: T): Optional<T> {
    val optional: Optional<T> = Optional.of(t)
    return optional
}
```

Comment: Note there's an open issue to make `Optional` covariant: [KT-54889](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-54889/Consider-making-java.lang.Optional-covariant)

Comment: Thanks, I edited to mention it. I guess that would be wise indeed.

Comment: "the third thing is that Optional factory functions like of and ofNullable actually return the non-nullable projection of the type you pass". How come? The signature of is `public static <T> Optional<T> of(T value)`
I don't see any indication that would say that it returns a non-nullable projection of the type. Can you think of example of similar function (defined in java) that returns a nullable projection of the type? I don't understand why the type suddenly changes. The signature in java looked clear, we pass T and we get Optional of T.

Comment: I don't actually know why, sorry, this is just what I could observe. This might be some Kotlin compiler magic to better reflect in the type system what actually happens for Optional specifically. And it's an unfortunate choice when combined with the invariance of `Optional`.

Comment: Note that Java's `T` doesn't say anything about its nullability. So the Java signature actually can correspond to both `<T>` and `<T & Any>` (that's one of the problems with Java's generics)

Comment: Not so much a problem with Java generics as with nullability not being part of Java's type system _at all_.

Comment: (For completeness: I know of one case in which Optional would score over a simple nullable type, which is when the Optionals can be nested and you might need to distinguish an `Optional.empty()` from an `Optional.of(Optional.empty())`.  But I've never seen such a case; I suspect it would be a strong code smell.  Since nullable types are fully idiomatic, safe, efficient, and well-supported, I'd strongly advise people to use them instead!)

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that the factory-methods of the `Optional`-class returns an `Optional` of a "definitely non-nullable" type, which is denoted `T & Any`. However, because your type parameter `T` is nullable, that doesn't match your return type (because `Optional<T>` is invariant). Your type parameter is nullable as long as you don't mark it as a subtype of `Any`.

You can fix your problem by doing this:

```kotlin
fun <T : Any> returnOptionalOf(t: T?): Optional<T> {
    val optional: Optional<T> = Optional.ofNullable(t)
    return optional
}
```

Or if you want it to still accept a nullable type parameter, you could make it return a "definitely non-nullable" type with `T & Any`. This was new in Kotlin 1.7. Like this:

```kotlin
fun <T> returnOptionalOf(t: T): Optional<T & Any> {
    val optional: Optional<T & Any> = Optional.ofNullable(t)
    return optional
}
```

Comment: *the Optional-class expects a non-nullable type parameter* - I initially wanted to write this but that's not true. We can happily declare an `Optional<String?>` if we want to. However, all `Optional` factory functions seem to return an `Optional<T & Any>` no matter the type parameter we want to force. For instance, `Optional.of<String?>("abc")`  still returns an `Optional<String>`, which doesn't play well with the fact that `Optional` is invariant in `T`.

Comment: Oh, right @Joffrey. Good catch. I'll try to incorporate that into my answer.